# symfony2 assign icon to twig variable

Tags: variables, symfony, printing, icons, twig

Using Symfony2.3.4 with Twig.
I need to assign an icon to a twig variable and then print the variable, can this be done at all??
for example:

```
{% set var = '<i class="glyphicon-user"></i>' %}
```

this obviously doesn't work, it's just to make my idea clear, it prints this text:

```
<i class="glyphicon-user"></i>
```

I need to print the icon itself.

Tips appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method will work you just need to call the raw filter with it:

```
{% set var = '<i class="glyphicon-user"></i>' %}
{{ var|raw }}
```

Without `raw` twig will escape html entities

Comment: If this answered your question it would be appreciated if you would mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: the thing is I had not noticed my rep is now above 15, it must have happened just now, because before that I could not up vote any answers, there it is, thanks again